# How to update jetpack compose slider state outside of the slider

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

So, I'm using the Jetpack compose for my app and I have a state with a float value in the viewModel. This value can be updated outside of the slider; but also from the slider when the finger is lifted (I'd rather not update it while the user is still sliding the finger).
I'd like the slider to reflect the value when it's updated from outside the slider; but when I let the slider internal state depend on it, the slider won't update whatsoever unless from the external state (there's no sliding motion). What am I doing wrong?

```
            val sliderState = mutableStateOf(viewModel.state.value) 
            Slider(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                value = sliderState.value,
                onValueChangeFinished = {
                    viewModel.state.value = sliderState.value
                },
                onValueChange = {
                    sliderState.value = it
                },
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update the model value in the `onValueChange`. You never need an internal state, since that causes ambiguity. Just follow the "single source of truth" principle.

Use this

```
Slider(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                value = viewModel.state.value,
                onValueChange = {
                    viewModel.state.value = it
                },
            )
```

Ditch the internal variable.

No need to implement `onValueFinished`.
It will be constantly updated in the model and read in the Composable at the same time. Also, if you won't update it continuously in the model, the slider won't slide in this scenario.

On the other hand, if you are implementing something like a slider that slides continuously but only updates a specific value when the user lifts there finger off the slider, use your exact code, but just apply a `remember` to your internal variable.

```
val sliderState = remember { mutableStateOf(viewModel.state.value) }
```

Although, this is not something commonly required. If you are doing it for performance purposes, it is not required. Compose is built on top of this structure so it efficiently handles these rapid state changes.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but think something like this would work if viewModel.state is a StateFlow.

```kotlin
val sliderState = viewModel.state.collectAsState()
val localState = remember { mutableStateOf(sliderState.value) }
Slider(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    value = localState.value,
    onValueChangeFinished = {
        viewModel.state.value = localState.value
    },
    onValueChange = {
        localState.value = it
    }
)
```

Comment: You should AVOID using `Flow` and `LiveData` in place of `MutableState<T>`

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: Official Recommendations.

Comment: Interesting. Got a link to those?

Comment: Take the official state-codelab. They have a detailed walk-through on replacing `LiveData` with `SnapshotStateList<T>` (a type of mutable state-holding list, designed specifically for Compose). Why even the question? Isn't it obvious that if the developers spent months building stuff for Compose that could be done with `LiveData` and `Flow`, it would clearly have been done for a purpose? A million crystal clear reasons can I think of off the top of my head, boilerplate being one of the biggest apparent.

Comment: [For Convenience](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state). I've recommended this to so many people I have memorized the URL by heart.